# Execution time and gettimeofday on ubuntu / i7

Tags: c

To measure execution time of a function in C,how accurate is the POSIX function `gettimeofday()` in **Ubuntu 12.04** on an **Intel i7** ? And why ? If its hard to say,then how to find out ? I can't find a straight answer on this.

Comment: execution time of a function

Comment: This might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392278/measure-time-in-linux-getrusage-vs-clock-gettime-vs-clock-vs-gettimeofday

Comment: What kind of run time are we talking about? If you are trying to time things in the millisecond scale, `gettimeofday()` is horribly inappropriate. However, if it your program runs for, e.g. a week, `gettimeofday()` might be sufficient for your needs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are building a stopwatch, you want a consistent clock that does not adjust to any time servers.

```
#include <time.h>
...
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &ts);
```

If `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` does not exist, use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead. If you want time of day, you still should not use `gettimeofday`.

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
```

The timer for such clocks is high resolution, but it shifts. The `timespec` supports resolution as small as **nanoseconds**, but your computer will likely only be able to measure somewhere in the microseconds.

`gettimeofday` returns a `timeval`, which has a resolution in **microseconds**.

Comment: This is an answer to the question the OP should have asked, but not to the one he did ask.

Comment: It returns time in microseconds but the actual accuracy is not microseconds (not 1 microsecond), http://stackoverflow.com/a/7760992/390913

Comment: @perreal That is correct. I only meant that the data structure was capable of holding microseconds.

Comment: @perreal The accuracy of any timing function will always depend on the hardware involved, which TheBuzzSaw clearly stated in his answer

Answer (score 0):

`gettimeofday` should be accurate enough, at least for comparing relative performance. But, in order to smooth out inaccuracies due to context switching and IO related delays you should run the function, say, at least hundreds of times and get the average.

You can tune the number of times you need to execute the function by making sure you get approximately the same result each time you benchmark the function.

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760992/390913) to measure the accuracy of gettimeofday in your system.

Comment: You should not use `gettimeofday`.

Comment: the question does not ask whether or not we should use it though

Answer (score -2):

You can use gettimeofday() at start and end of code to find the difference between starting time and finishing time of program. like

```
//start = gettimeofday
//your code here
//end = gettimeofday
```

Execution time will be difference between the 2
But it **depends on how much load is one the machine** is at that point. So not a reliable method.

You can also use:

```
time ./a.out
```

assuming your program is a.out

Comment: The question was about accuracy. You don't answer the question. -1

Comment: @thejh Getting execution time from gettimeofday is not a reliable method. and hence inaccurate.