# Remove character from array where spaces and punctuation marks are found

Tags: c++, string, cstring

In my program, I am checking whole cstring, if any spaces or punctuation marks are found, just add empty character to that location but the complilor is giving me an error: empty character constant.

Please help me out, in my loop i am checking like this

```
if(ispunct(str1[start])) {
    str1[start]=''; // << empty character constant. 
}
if(isspace(str1[start])) {
    str1[start]=''; // << empty character constant. 
}
```

This is where my errors are please correct me.

for eg the word is `str,, ing,` output should be `string`.

Comment: What is an "empty character?"

Comment: @Angew A removed one ;) ...

Comment: @jrd1 No, it's not a dupe (especially not concerning the accepted answer there)! There's no need for _'shrinking'_ or dynamically resizing the array, see my answer & more comments downwards ...

Comment: @user3215228 Please note my additional recommendations about _real_ [tag:c++] implementations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this (as you asked for `cstring` explicitly):

```
char str1[100] = "str,, ing";

if(ispunct(str1[start]) || isspace(str1[start])) {
    strncpy(str1 + start, str1 + start + 1, strlen(str1) - start + 1);
}
```

Well, doing this just in pure [c](/questions/tagged/c) language, there are more efficient solutions (have a look at [@MichaelPlotke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307154/michael-plotke)'s answer for details).

But as you also explicitly ask for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I'd recommend a solution as follows:

**Note** you *can* use the [standard c++ algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) for 'plain' c-style character arrays also. You just have to place your predicate conditions for removal into a small helper functor and use it with the `std::remove_if()` algorithm:

```
struct is_char_category_in_question {
    bool operator()(const char& c) const;
};
```

And later use it like:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

// Best chance to have the predicate elided to be inlined, when writing 
// the functor like this:
struct is_char_category_in_question {
    bool operator()(const char& c) const {
        return std::ispunct(c) || std::isspace(c);
    }
};

int main() {
    static char str1[100] = "str,, ing";
    size_t size = strlen(str1);

    // Using std::remove_if() is likely to provide the best balance from perfor-
    // mance  and code size efficiency you can expect from your compiler 
    // implementation.
    std::remove_if(&str1[0], &str1[size + 1], is_char_category_in_question());

    // Regarding specification of the range definitions end of the above state-
    // ment, note we have to add 1 to the strlen() calculated size, to catch the 
    // closing `\0` character of the c-style string being copied correctly and
    // terminate the result as well!

    std::cout << str1 << endl; // Prints: string
}
```

See this compilable and working sample also [here](http://ideone.com/WV9xQc).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can conjecture that it may have something to do with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6987247/866930.

Comment: What's bad with using strncpy() in [tag:c++]?? I have many situations, where I simply can't afford the conveniences and usage of `std::string ` ...

Comment: Your use of `remove_if` on the C-String is _completely_ wrong as `remove_if` won't remove the characters from a statically allocated array, but only keep the contents in memory unreplaced in the remainder of the string.

Comment: @jrd1 At least [this](http://ideone.com/WV9xQc) works fine?? It doesn't matter if the array is statically allocated or not IMHO (did you mean **const** inputs??)!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19139765/866930

Comment: @jrd1 Good research, but not really relevant for what's asked for here, it's not necessary to _'shrink'_ anything. If it has a fixed size, it has a fixed size, and nothing in my answer will ever act outside the array boundaries at any time ...

Comment: Hadn't seen `remove_if` before. Seems cool. Still, I find my c-style answer more readable.

Comment: @MichaelPlotke Which ever more than a single line code could be **more readable** than `remove_if()`?? The behavior is pretty well defined and you can easily find the [reference for it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Admittedly `remove_if` is intuitively named and, as you say, documented. On the other hand, C++ hides things in a way that makes them difficult to truly grasp. What is going on under the hood? Nothing good (based on efficiency comparisons).

Comment: @MichaelPlotke Refer to my _other comment_ please ...

Comment: I don't get the downvotes on this answer! May be s.o. can explain or propose improvements??

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an empty character.

If you mean a space then change `''` to `' '` (with a space in it).

If you mean `NUL` then change it to `'\0'`.

Comment: No i dont mean null character , I just want spaces and punctuation marks to be replaced with empty spaces.

Comment: @user3215228 What is an "empty space?" Do you mean the space character? Or do you actually want to *remove* the spaces and punctuations from the string?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove those characters? You can't do that by assigning them a value. You need to shift all the characters in the string after that position back one position or something.

Comment: for eg the word is str,,  ing, output should be string

Comment: @user3215228 As paulpro mentioned you want to **remove** the characters. That's a completely different operation, I recommend to use `std::string` for doing this, otherwise copy the rest of the string to the location where you found one of your characters in question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the answer is no longer relevant now that the OP has edited the question.  Leaving up for posterity's sake.

If you're wanting to add a null character, use '\0'.  If you're wanting to use a different character, using the appropriate character for that.  You can't assign it nothing.  That's meaningless.  That's like saying

```
int myHexInt = 0x;
```

or

```
long long myIndeger = L;
```

The compiler will error.  Put in the value you wanted.  In the char case, that's a value from 0 to 255.

Comment: No i dont mean null character , I just want spaces and punctuation marks to be replaced with empty spaces.

Comment: Okay, well use a space character, then.  `str1[start]=' ';`

Just don't try to assign a character to nothing.  That's like saying `int x = ;` and hoping it compiles.

Comment: @m24p The OP want's to replace space char with space char??

Comment: I thought the "isspace" function was be checking for all types of whitespace, eg tab characters etc.  The OP has since made it clear the real question should be how to remove characters.

Comment: @m24p I've been clarifying, but doesn't matter ...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

From the edit to OP's question, it's apparent that he/she wanted to *trim* a string of punctuation and space characters.

As detailed in the flagged possible duplicate, one way is to use `remove_copy_if`:

```
string test = "THisisa test;;';';';";
string temp, finalresult;

remove_copy_if(test.begin(), test.end(), std::back_inserter(temp), ptr_fun<int, int>(&ispunct));
remove_copy_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(finalresult), ptr_fun<int, int>(&isspace));
```

ORIGINAL

Examining your question, **replacing spaces with spaces is redundant**, so you really need to figure out **how to replace punctuation characters with spaces**. You can do so using a comparison function (by wrapping `std::ispunct`) in tandem with `std::replace_if` from the STL:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool is_punct(const char& c) {
    return ispunct(c);
}

int main() {
    string test = "THisisa test;;';';';";
    char test2[] = "THisisa test;;';';'; another";

    size_t size = sizeof(test2)/sizeof(test2[0]);

    replace_if(test.begin(), test.end(), is_punct, ' ');//for C++ strings
    replace_if(&test2[0], &test2[size-1], is_punct, ' ');//for c-strings

    cout << test << endl;
    cout << test2 << endl;
}
```

This outputs:

```
THisisa test
THisisa test         another
```

Comment: To the downvoter, was there something that could be improved upon? If so, I'd welcome any feedback.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No problem. It's an honest mistake: these things do happen.

Comment: _'To the downvoter ..'_ Sorry, wasn't a mistake: The question asks for **removing** that characters, not replacing by spaces (`'\0x32'`)! You'd better mentioned `std::remove_if` ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I only now saw that edit: I'm working on it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a duplicate for this question, at least the accepted answer doesn't apply ...

Answer (score -1):

As I don't like the accepted answer, here's mine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    char str[100] = "str,, ing";
    int bad = 0;
    int cur = 0;
    while (str[cur] != '\0') {
        if (bad < cur && !ispunct(str[cur]) && !isspace(str[cur])) {
                str[bad] = str[cur];
        }
        if (ispunct(str[cur]) || isspace(str[cur])) {
            cur++;
        }
        else {
            cur++;
            bad++;
        }
    }
    str[bad] = '\0';
    fprintf(stdout, "cur = %d; bad = %d; str = %s\n", cur, bad, str);
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs `cur = 18; bad = 14; str = string`

This has the advantage of being <del>more efficient and more readable</del>, hm, well, in a style I happen to like better (see comments for a lengthy debate / explanation).

Comment: Yes, after fixing your code a bit [it works fine](http://ideone.com/FNapEm) and is more efficient (at least vs. the `strncpy()` version). It would be nice to have a confirmation, that the `remove_if()` sample **really is** less efficient as what's given from your answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, your code really truly is **significantly** less efficient. About 16 times less efficient (on my machine). I've just been bench-marking each. Feel free to duplicate my findings.

Comment: Good point, then! Could you show a bit more about your benchmarking methods? I'm concerned, since `remove_if()` could be easily implemented in a similar manner as you did, and I usually assume that the standard implementations **are** as efficient as ever possible to cover the applicable use cases. Sadly, that might not be true for _all_ compiler and c++ standard library implementations!

Comment: The bench-mark simply uses [the top answer's method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468596/c-programming-calculate-elapsed-time-in-milliseconds-unix) to time a loop of 10000000 iterations of each method with the string "str,, ing".

Comment: To cite the reference of `remove_if`: _'Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten. '_ That let's me assume a correct implementation should follow your algo ...

Comment: Hmm, I'm currently trying to replicate the benchmark tests as you proposed on [ideone](http://ideone.com/rp5NxA). I seem to got stuck on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760951/gettimeofday-c-inconsistency) :( ... Could you clarify about your toolchain used for the benchmark (I'm afraid it's a toolchain specific problem as mentioned)? (My previous comments emphasis should have been on _shifting_ BTW)

Comment: Linux 3.12.9-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 31 10:22:54 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux |
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140206 (prerelease) |
While gettimeofday is not the best bench-marking method, it is fairly accurate and simple to implement. I've never had trouble with it...

Comment: OK! I've just been able to have your benchmarks compiled on ideone (a bit strange, it's necessary to include `time.h` **and** `sys\time.h` :( ): [**remove_if()** sample](http://ideone.com/rp5NxA), [**c-style while loop** sample](http://ideone.com/GEjP9W), and I must admit your findings about the performance deficiencies seem right. That really makes me concerned about GCC's implementation (I've been using an older version for the samples, but I don't think that matters much). May be a good reason to spawn another question on SO about this!

Comment: This one relaxes me a lot: [std::remove_if GCC implementation isn't efficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767415/stdremove-if-gcc-implementation-isnt-efficient#21767545)

Comment: So no real improvements from your solution, sorry ...

Comment: Confirmed. I still like c-style code better, but that's just me. Thanks for taking the time to figure this out.

Comment: _'Thanks for taking the time to figure this out.'_ De nada! I was just curios (and a bit concerned) myself ... My usual experience is: **you can't provide better efficiency easily** compared with c++ standard library implementations. But as we see (from my bad former sample) you might use them blatantly wrong :( ...

Comment: FWIW my C-style solution would be like `char *dst = str, *src = str; while (*src) { if !ispunct(*src) && !isspace(*src) { *dst++ = *src; } ++src; } *dst = 0;`. And that's almost exactly what `remove_if` will do *if* you can get everything properly inlined, except that of course it doesn't know about nul terminated strings.